# The map $\phi :G\rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism iff $\{(g,\phi(g)):g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G'$

Tags: group-theory

The map $\phi :G\rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism iff $\{(g,\phi(g)):g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G'$.

Proving (=>) is easy, but I cannot prove the other direction. Any hints? Also, is the identity in $G\times G'$ necessarily $(e,\phi(e))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
Assume that $\{(g,\phi(g)):g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$'.  Remember that you're starting with the function $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$.  All you need to show is that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Let $(g,\phi(g))$ and $(h,\phi(h))$ be in your subgroup.  What is $\phi(gh)$?

Comment: Since $(g,\phi(g))$ and $(h,\phi(h))$ are in the subgroup so is $(gh,\phi(g)\phi(h))$. But $(gh,\phi(gh))$ is as well. With $\phi$ being a function, $(gh,\phi(g)\phi(h))=(gh,\phi(gh))$, i.e. $\phi(g)\phi(h)=\phi(gh)$. Sometimes you just need a nudge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\{\,(g,\phi(g)):g\in G\,\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G'$. We want to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, i.e., that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$. But this follows because with $(a,\phi(a))$ and $ (b,\phi(b))$ also their product $(ab,\phi(a)\phi(b))$ is an element of our subgroup. By the way it is defined, we conclude that it is in fact the element $(ab,\phi(ab))$, i.e., $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab)$, as desired.